# Having method accept unspecified/generic Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I use Enums for sort-columns on searches, and hence I have different enums for different types ie.

```
public enum SortablePersonFields
{
    Id,
    Name
}

public enum SortableCarFields
{
    Color,
    Price
}
```

I currently have a helper method that helps me generate the column headers for my view, and it needs to know which column the search is currently sorted by:

```
public static IHtmlString SortablePersonHeader(this AjaxHelper helper, string headerTitle, SortablePersonFields sortablePersonField, ISortableSearchCriteria searchCriteria){
    if (searchCriteria.SortablePersonField== sortablePersonField)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

I wish to make this method generic by having it accept an unspecified Enum, but I found this difficult as Enums don't support Interfaces or Inheritance. Is there a good way around this?

The ISortableSearchCriteria currently has a SortablePersonFields, so it would need to be generic aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no enum constraint, but you can do something like:

```
ISortable<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IComparable
{
    TEnum Sort { get; }
}

public static IHtmlString SortablePersonHeader<TEnum>(this AjaxHelper helper, string headerTitle, TEnum sort, ISortable<TEnum> searchCriteria)
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable
{
    if(! typeof(TEnum).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("Requires enum type");
    if(sort.Equals(searchCriteria.Sort))
    {
    }
}
```